# issue in displaying blog image on blog page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am having a blog page in my website... There are different posts ... on left side blog image is displayed , on right side text is written..when i click on particular blog, the main page of that post appears with image on the top and text down the image.
The issue is that on my blog page the left side images are not displayed rather default image is displayed.. bt when i click on post.. the main page of that particular post is having image...

```
 <div class="blog-img mainimg" style="">
<?php $blogmainimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
<?php if($blogmainimg[0] == '') : ?>
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/Noimg.png" />  
 <?php else : ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
```

only "if" is working.... else is not working
on blog page, all the posts are having NOIMG.png.. which is wrong

???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try a more simplified solution. This uses the has_post_thumbnail() to check if a featured image is specified, since you really do not need to utilize the wp_get_attachment_image_src() in the provided code.

```
<div class="blog-img mainimg" style="">
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) : ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/Noimg.png" />  
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This uses has_post_thumbnail() to see if the post has one specified, if it does, it will display it uses the_post_thumbnail(). If not, it will revert to the default.

If this doesn't work, than it could be an issue of using the_post_thumbnail(), this would mostly depend on your loop that's displaying the blog posts. If that is the case, try this:

```
<div class="blog-img mainimg" style="">
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) : ?>
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/Noimg.png" />  
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

If this still does not solve the issue, please post the loop for your page as well, and I can further troubleshoot it.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? What is happening for posts with thumbnails and posts without thumbnails? Could you post your entire Loop so we have a bit more to work with?

Comment: the_post_thumbnail(); not retrieving any thumbnail back....
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) : ?>
This code is working as i tried NOIMG in IF part....it executes... it means no error in IF statement... problem is in the_post_thumbnail();

Comment: <div class="blog-img mainimg" style="">
                    <?php $blogmainimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );  ?>
     <?php if($blogmainimg[0] == '') : ?>
                      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/blog-Noimg.png" />  
                    <?php else : ?>
                     <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>   
This only the entire loop

Comment: This is a blog list page, right? A page listing multiple posts? If not I misunderstood your original post. If it is a list page, there should be a Loop. Generally it is a while loop, or possibly a for each loop. Typically something like this: <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> followed by more code to set up all the content displayed.